# Will python.subprocess(cppBinaryExe) compromise cppBinaryExe's performance?

Tags: python, linux

i am quite new to python.subprocess()

if i folk a new process from python, will the execution speed of this new process be compromised?

imagine that i have the

```
#python 
import subprocess
subprocess.call( MyBinary )
```

basically, is there any difference between

```
./MyBinary
```

and

```
./python ruMyBinary.py
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A separate process is a separate process.  It competes for OS resources with all other processes "fairly".

Your python process that simply does `subprocess.call` is a process, and does consume some system resources.  But relatively few, since it will be waiting for a system call to finish.  It will occupy a slot in the process table, so it does have a microscopic impact.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from having to actually run the python interpreter, no.  So your last example will take some slight time before `MyBinary` to parse and run the python program and some slight time after it completes to terminate the python program.  And the python program will be an existing process which takes up a pid and some amount of memory.

So the running speed of one long-running program won't be affekted.  Hovever, if you run your executable thousands of times, any extra wrapping, wether in python or in something else, will cost.

Answer (score 0):

No, the process runs just as if started by any other means.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot1 

this is the first question that i posted on this website!